# Can I use an EF6 convention to name Many to Many relationship tables?

Tags: entity-framework

I have so far been unable to find an example of naming many to many join tables by convention (e.g., not by referencing particular relationships via the ModelBuilder fluent api. I'd like to be able to configure this by convention so that I don't have to keep overriding the name in every relationship.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way of changing the convention. I just looked into this. You either get the default

`<Table1><Table2>`

convention or you have to use the API configuration to create  a custom name for each join table.